# 4 pin inductor for buck convertor

Tags: inductor

I am designing a buck converter. I have found an inductor to use for it but it consists of 4 pins. Will I not need only 2 pins? The inductor is: WURTH ELEKTRONIK  7446622002  CHOKE, COMMON MODE, 2.2MH, 2A.

Heres the link to datasheet:http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1735935.pdf

Can you please tell me how can i use (which pins to connect) this inductor for my application?

Comment: As the datasheet indicates, this is not a simple inductor. its a common-mode choke, intended to be used in a power-line filtering application, and consists of 2 inductors wound on the same core. It probably wouldn't work as well as you hope in a buck converter.

Answer (score 1):

That is likely to be not a suitable inductor for a buck switching regulator. It's a common mode choke and has two coils - it is intended for suppressing emissions amongst other things and not the best choice for your application. It will likely saturate if you try to use one of the windings (the other being superfluous in a buck circuit). With saturation comes poor efficiency and overheating. What does the manufacturer of the chip (buck regulator) recommend?

Comment: Manufacturer didnt recommend anything. I need an inductor with 1.2mH and 2A rated current ratings. Any ideas where I can find?

Comment: Farnell are pretty good.